# Windows Task Scheduler: SQLCMD command does not return error when fails?

Tags: error-handling, sqlcmd, windows-task-scheduler

I've scheduled a task on Windows Task Scheduler, that calls the command SQLCMD using the parameter: `-i "path\script.sql"`

My problem is this:

- My script starts with: `USE [DatabaseX]`
- DatabaseX does not exist on the server, so the script fails.
- But the Scheduled Task ends with a Successful result, even if the script fails.

I need to see that the last run failed in the scheduled task. Or other place, but somewhere.

Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but the task itself started and completed. That there was an error _in the script_ that the scheduler executed is of no concern to the scheduler. You need to report script errors and check for them somewhere else. Where is up to you.